# How to produce black smoke using chemical reaction

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Tell me the requirements and procedure for **producing black smoke using chemical  reactions**.

Comment: is it a theoretical question or practical one? If second, what is the situation we are talking about?

Answer (score 3):

When ignited, mixtures of potassium chlorate, charcoal and anthracene (or naphthalene) produce black smoke.

**However, note that milling and grinding dry mixtures of potassium chlorate and charcoal is a well-known method to cause an explosion and severely harm or kill yourself!**